# I get jawr net.jawr.web.minification.JSMin$UnterminatedRegExpLiteralException

Tags: java, jawr

Mainly am writing this as a self-answer since it took me a long time to discover the issue, my project uses jawr for minifying resources js and CSS, this is useful because it elements the comments automatically without exposing it to production, in addition to minifying itself and separating modules easily by grouping resources as bundles of 2 types, debug and production.

**Reference:**

[jawr webstie](https://j-a-w-r.github.io/)

**Problem:**

I started to get this exception, in my tests that prepare my resources, as part of the deployment job, this creates a folder with assets with minified, CSS and JS, and to be served as gzip.

```
net.jawr.web.minification.JSMin$UnterminatedRegExpLiteralException
    at net.jawr.web.minification.JSMin.action(JSMin.java:277)
    at net.jawr.web.minification.JSMin.jsmin(JSMin.java:353)
    at com.mycomanyname.jobs.PrepareAssetsTest.minifyJs(PrepareAssetsTest.java:84)
    at com.mycomanyname.jobs.PrepareAssetsTest.minimizeAssets(PrepareAssetsTest.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

**I have tried:**
Checking on google ofcourse, and checkout commits one by one backward to see what broke it.

Comment: I have put this question, because i could not find any clue on internet about such issue.

Answer (score 0):

After checking my tree one by one, it appeared this was the reason of the bug

[image: one of my js i use]

So when i removed this line the error was gone.

```
//# sourceMappingURL=jquery.countdown.min.map
```

I did the same for all my files, and the reason was that i started
relying on CDN to get my resources, plus doing a lot of refactoring, so these files with the same trend started to increase, later on, i found the problem and deleted these lines.

**P.S:** I still not sure why its so important to have this line in first place, i just copied and pasted from CDNJS, in this screen shot case

```
jquery.countdownTimer.2.1.0.min.js
```